# I want PayPal integration with SOAP in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, soap

I have done a complete order with ccsave using SOAP:

```
$setCustCrtPayMethod = $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($session, $_REQUEST['CartId'], array(
    'po_number' => null,
    'method' => 'ccsave',
    'cc_cid' => $_REQUEST['cc_cid'],
    'cc_owner' => $_REQUEST['cc_owner'],
    'cc_number' => $_REQUEST['cc_number'],
    'cc_type' => $_REQUEST['cc_type'],
    'cc_exp_year' => $_REQUEST['cc_exp_year'],
    'cc_exp_month' => $_REQUEST['cc_exp_month']
));
```

But when I add this

```
$paymentMethod = array(
     'method' => 'paypal_standard',
     'last_trans_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
 );
```

in

```
$setCustCrtPayMethod = $proxy->shoppingCartPaymentMethod($session,  array(
    'po_number' => null,
    'method' => 'paypal_standard',
```

);

It will send a blank response. How can I configure PayPal?

Answer (score 2):

I think the integration of PayPal via SOAP API will not work like this. PayPal depends on doing a redirect after the checkout which is processed by the Magento PayPal module.

You are trying to use this functionality via SOAP API which will not work as the Magento module cannot perform a redirect on the platform you're calling the SOAP request from.